# s3 cross account access with default kms key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an s3 bucket in my account which has SSE enabled using default `aws-kms` key. I wish to provide read access to another account to my bucket.

I have followed the following link to provide access:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-denied-error-s3/

I am using `aws s3 ls <s3://bucket_name>` and `aws s3 cp <path to s3 object> .`  to download the object

I tried providing cross-account access to a bucket without SSE enabled. I was successfully able to retrieve bucket details and download object.  However, when I try to download object from a bucket with SSE enabled I get `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied` exception.  I am able to list objects from the SSE-enabled bucket, just not download them.

My bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<Account_B_AWS_Account_Id>:role/ReadOnly"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<Account_B_AWS_Account_Id>:role/ReadOnly"
              ]
            },
            "Action": [
              "kms:Encrypt",
              "kms:Decrypt",
              "kms:ReEncrypt*",
              "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
              "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The ReadOnly role in the account has read permissions to all aws services. In addition I attached the following policy to the role as well

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SomeProperites",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:ListBucketByTags",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:DescribeJob",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SomePermission",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "KMSWriteKey",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I believe I am not able to getObject due to KMS decryption since I able to download with a SSE-disabled bucket. Is my policy above correct? Do I need to provide some additional permissions if using default kms keys?  Is it possible to use default kms keys and provide cross-account access?

Comment: That looks right to me. Maybe try specifying the account number and region in resource of the KMSWriteKey? Ex: "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:<accountNumber>:key/<key-number>"

This question is pretty old, did you figure it out? If so feel free to answer your own question, it's actually encouraged by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 9):

->  SSE enabled using default aws-kms key

This is the AWS Managed KMS key, you can only view the key policy of it. You cannot edit the key policy of it. So you will not be able to do cross account s3 object sharing with SSE-KMS AWS managed key.

Please switch to use `SSE-KMS Customer Managed Key` and grant the cross-account prinicipal with the `descrypt` action in the selected KMS CMK.

Answer (score -1):

To grant access to an AWS KMS-encrypted bucket in Account A to a user in Account B, you must have these permissions in place:

- The bucket policy in Account A must grant access to Account B.
- The AWS KMS key policy in Account A must grant access to the user in Account B.
- The AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) user policy in Account B must grant the user access to both the bucket and the key in Account A.

See more information here:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-denied-error-s3/

Comment: The question mentions explicitly "default kms key". Cross-account access using SSE-S3 will not be possible unless a role in the same account is assumed.