# How do I grant cross account access to an encrypted bucket with a simple s3 bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I have an encrypted s3 bucket

I want to give another account access to this bucket

Normally I would just do this:

```
  {
     "Sid":"get",
     "Effect":"Allow",
     "Principal":{
        "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::99999999999:root"
     },
     "Action":[
        "s3:Get*",
     ],
     "Resource":[
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
     ]
  },
```

But this bucket is encrypted and they get this error:

```
upload failed: ./test to s3://my-bucket/test An error occurred (KMS.NotFoundException) when calling the PutObject operation: Key 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:99999999999:key/blahbalbhablhalbhalbh' does not exist
```

Looks like they need KMS access? I can give their account access to the kms key with the kms policy and that will fix it? If so I need to create a custom key to edit the policy right? I want to assign their account ID access to the encrypted bucket directly

Comment: Account A trying to upload file to S3 which located in Account B?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59044296/9931092

Comment: Are they using the awscli to upload? Are they supplying `--sse aws:kms`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re on the right path! You need to create a customer managed KMS key (CMK) and update the KMS key policy to use the key for decryption. Use that encryption key when you put items in the bucket. Make sure the KMS policy is least privilege!

Comment: I also suggest including the region in the key resource in the IAM policy attached to the role you are using to access the bucket. For some reason it didn't work unless I included it.

Comment: See also this answer - you must use the full KMS key ARN for S3 default encryption https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65226175/kms-not-found-exception-in-aws-cross-account-s3-putobject-encrypted-by-aws-manag/74186484#74186484