# KMS Not found Exception in AWS Cross Account S3 PutObject encrypted by AWS Managed Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-kms

I am trying to put a dummy file from Glue which is in Account B to S3 bucket in account A. S3 bucket(test-bucket) is having AWS-KMS encryption with aws/s3 Managed Key enabled.

1. I added below permissions in Account A- S3 bucket (test-bucket):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Deny PutObject if NOT using correct KMS Encryption Key",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "",
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "<ARN_KMS_ACCOUNT_A>"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow Glue Role in Application account to put objects in the S3 bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<IAM_Glue_Role_ARN>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Only allow writes to my bucket with bucket owner full control",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<IAM_Glue_Role_ARN>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Added below policy to IAM Glue role in Account B

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "<ARN_KMS_ACCOUNT_A>",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my Glue Code:

```
s3.put_object(
    Bucket='output',
    Key='_SUCCESS',
    ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms',
    SSEKMSKeyId='<ARN_KMS_ACCOUNT_A>'
)
```

Getting below error while running this code from Account B Glue:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (KMS.NotFoundException) when calling the PutObject operation: Invalid arn ap-southeast-2
```

Any thoughts on this.?

Comment: Does this make sense actually? "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "",

Answer (score 0):

The AWS managed keys `aws/s3` can only be used in the same account i.e. where the key exists (in your case, its Account A). You can either try to use the `aws/s3` CMK from Account B OR create a customer managed CMK in Account A and share it with Account B following the steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-modifying-external-accounts.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things:

1. For the policy on the bucket, `Deny` permissions should be always at the end after all the `Allow` permissions. And remove the `condition` on the `Deny` permissions. You want to block all traffic that's not authorized.
2. Use a managed KMS key. And on that key, grant `kms:decrypt` to the glue role on the key's policy.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-encryption.html#bucket-encryption-update-bucket-policy) you must use the full ARN of the encryption key so cross-account succeeds. Using an alias or key ID does not work.

- Be aware of the following when using encryption for cross-account operations:
  The AWS managed key (aws/s3) is used when a AWS KMS key Amazon Resource Name (ARN) or alias is not provided at request time, nor via the bucket's default encryption configuration.
- If you're uploading or accessing S3 objects using AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) principals that are in the same AWS account as your KMS key, you can use the AWS managed key (aws/s3).
- Use a customer managed key if you want to grant cross-account access to your S3 objects. You can configure the policy of a customer managed key to allow access from another account.
- If specifying your own KMS key, you should use a fully qualified KMS key key ARN. When using a KMS key alias, be aware that AWS KMS will resolve the key within the requester’s account. This can result in data encrypted with a KMS key that belongs to the requester, and not the bucket administrator.
- You must specify a key that you (the requester) have been granted Encrypt permission to. For more information, see Allows key users to use a KMS key for cryptographic operations in the AWS Key Management Service Developer Guide.

The S3 bucket should look something like this

[image: S3 encryption policy]